# Where is the place for dependencies resolving using IoC within WPF app?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ioc-container, caliburn.micro

I have read in "Dependency Injection in .NET" by Mark Seemann that there should be a single place (per each) where Register, Resolve and Release have to be called. Now, I'm trying to set up the environment of a new WPF project. Our team has decided to use Caliburn.Micro as MVVM-framework with MEF as IoC.
So, I clearly understand where Register has to be called, but what about Resolve?
I also have read in the book, that in ASP.NET MVC app there is a place where Resolve has to be called:

```
override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext,
                                           Type controllerType) {
    return (IController)this.container.Resolve(controllerType);
}
```

But where should the call reside within a WPF app? Besides, can Caliburn help somehow with accomplishing this issue?

Comment: Well, it seems that DisplayRootViewFor(Type viewModelType) in Bootstrapper.cs is intended for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But where should the call reside within a WPF app? Besides, can Caliburn help somehow with accomplishing this issue?

Actually Caliburn.Micro handles this part for you, because when you derive your bootstrapper from the existing `BootstrapperBase` or `Bootstrapper<TRootModel>`, those bootstrappers call a method called `Start()` that initiaties a sequence of activities which composes the entire object graph of your application starting with `TRootModel` or whatever you call `DisplayRootViewFor(Type viewModelType)` for.